# Split linked list into odd and even

Tags: c, linked-list

**Problem statement :**

*Implement the following*

```
void split_odd_and_even(LL_LinkedList_t * pList,        //![IN] : This is the input Linked List given to you.
                        LL_Node_t      ** pOddList,     //![OUT]: This is the Head node of the Odd List to be returned 
                        LL_Node_t      ** pEvenList );  //![OUT]: This is the Head node of the Even List to be returned
```

Conditions :

1. you cannot create new links/ additional links
2. the order of the links should remain the same e.g if original list is 1->2->3->4->5 the odd list should be 1->3->5 and even 2->4

**Code Review (Expectation):**
following apply for only implementation of split_odd_and_even
Anything outside the function is quick prototyping.

1. Missing Corner Cases
2. Pointers for readability for code
3. Logical Errors (excluding test case code , prototyping code  and dead code)

**Source Code:**

Linklist.h

```
#ifndef _LINKED_LIST_H_
#define _LINKED_LIST_H_

typedef unsigned int uint32_t;

typedef struct node_t
{
    uint32_t node_data;
    struct node_t   * pNextNode;
} LL_Node_t;

typedef struct
{
    LL_Node_t * head;
    LL_Node_t * tail;
    uint32_t count;
}LL_LinkedList_t;

void LL_Insert(LL_LinkedList_t * pList, uint32_t data);
void LL_Insert_Tail(LL_LinkedList_t * pList, uint32_t data);
void LL_Remove_Head(LL_LinkedList_t * pList);
void LL_Print_Node(LL_Node_t * pNode);
LL_Node_t * Find_tail_manual(LL_LinkedList_t * pList);
void split_odd_and_even(LL_LinkedList_t * pList,  LL_Node_t ** pOdd_List,LL_Node_t ** pEvenList );
void LL_RemoveNode(LL_LinkedList_t* pList, LL_Node_t * prev, LL_Node_t* current);
#endif
```

LinkList.c

```
/********************************************************************************
File:        linked_list.c
Project:
*******************************************************************************/
#include "Linklist.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void LL_Init(LL_LinkedList_t * pList)
{
    pList->head = NULL;
    pList->tail = NULL;
    pList->count = 0;
}

void LL_Insert_Tail(LL_LinkedList_t * pList, uint32_t data)
{
   LL_Node_t * tmp = (LL_Node_t *)malloc(sizeof(LL_Node_t));
    tmp->pNextNode = NULL;
    tmp->node_data = data;

   if(pList->count == 0)
   {
       pList->head = tmp;
       pList->tail = tmp;
   }else
   {
       pList->tail->pNextNode = tmp;
       pList->tail = tmp;
   }
   pList->count++;
}

void LL_Insert_Head(LL_LinkedList_t * pList, uint32_t data)
{
    LL_Node_t * tmp = pList->head;

    pList->head = (LL_Node_t *) malloc(sizeof(LL_Node_t));
    pList->tail = tmp;
    pList->count++;
}


void LL_Remove_Head(LL_LinkedList_t * pList)
{
    pList->head = pList->head->pNextNode;
    pList->count--;
}

void LL_Print_Node(LL_Node_t * pNode)
{
    printf("Node Addr: %p \n\t Node Data: %u \n\t pNextNode:%p \n\n",pNode, pNode->node_data, pNode->pNextNode);
}

LL_Node_t * Find_tail_manual(LL_LinkedList_t * pList)
{
    LL_Node_t * curr_node = pList->head;

    while (curr_node->pNextNode != NULL)
    {
        curr_node = curr_node->pNextNode;
    }

    return curr_node;
}

void LL_RemoveNode(LL_LinkedList_t * pList, LL_Node_t * prev, LL_Node_t* current)
{
    if(prev == NULL) //! This means you are trying to remove the head
    {
        pList->head = current->pNextNode;
        return;
    }
    //when node is in middle of the list
    prev->pNextNode = current->pNextNode;

}

void split_odd_and_even(LL_LinkedList_t * pList,  LL_Node_t ** pOddList,LL_Node_t ** pEvenList )
{
    LL_Node_t * current = pList->head;
    LL_Node_t * prev = NULL;
    LL_Node_t * tmp = NULL;
    LL_Node_t * removed_node;

    //! Pretend tail pointer is not available
    LL_Node_t * tail = Find_tail_manual(pList);

    //! Save off the tail
    tmp  = tail;

    // printf("tmp %p tmp %u \n", tmp, tmp->node_data);
    while(current != tmp)
    {
        // printf("current data : %d \n",current->node_data );
        if(current->node_data % 2 == 0)
        {

            //! Current node is removed
            LL_RemoveNode(pList, prev, current);
            removed_node = current;
            // printf("removed data %u\n", current->node_data);

            pList->tail->pNextNode = removed_node;
            pList->tail = removed_node;

            //!
            prev = current;
            current = removed_node->pNextNode;
            removed_node->pNextNode = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            prev = current;
            current = current->pNextNode;
        }
        // printf("current data end: %d \n",current->node_data );
    }

    //! handling for the last node
    if (current->node_data % 2 == 0)
    {
        //! Current node is removed
        LL_RemoveNode(pList, prev, current);
        removed_node = current;

        //! send the removed node to back of the list
        *pEvenList = current->pNextNode;
        pList->tail->pNextNode = removed_node;
        pList->tail = removed_node;

        //! Close the lists
        current->pNextNode = NULL;
        prev->pNextNode = NULL;

    }else
    {
        *pEvenList = current->pNextNode;
        current->pNextNode = NULL;
    }
    *pOddList = pList->head;
}

void main()
{
    uint32_t i = 0;
    LL_LinkedList_t linklist1;
    LL_Node_t * odd_head;
    LL_Node_t * even_head;

    //! Test Case for Insertion
    LL_Init(&linklist1);
    printf("Init Done!\n");
    for(i=0; i<11; i++)
    {
        LL_Insert_Tail(&linklist1, i);
    }

    //! Prints for visual checking the links (bcus DDD doesnt work on windows >:( ) 
    LL_Node_t * tmp = linklist1.head;
    do
    {
        LL_Print_Node(tmp);
        tmp = tmp->pNextNode;
    }while (tmp != NULL);
    // Find_tail_manual(&linklist1);

    //! Function to split the linklist into odd and even test
    split_odd_and_even(&linklist1, &odd_head, &even_head);
    tmp = odd_head;

    //! More visual checking
    printf("printing_odd_list \n");
    do
    {
        LL_Print_Node(tmp);
        tmp = tmp->pNextNode;
        // printf("tmp->pNextNode\n");
    }while (tmp != NULL);

    tmp = even_head;

    //! Even More visual checking
    // printf("printing_even_list \n");
    do
    {
        // printf("tmp->pNextNode :%p \n",tmp );
        LL_Print_Node(tmp);
        tmp = tmp->pNextNode;
    }while (tmp != NULL);
}
```

github repo [link](https://github.com/Dexobox/c/tree/5729c006d78fb0c8c47eb23543748b87f4fb3d04/Linklist2)

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: `LL_Insert_Head()` appears to be incomplete and not work. `LL_Remove_Head()` appears to leak memory, and crashes if the list is empty `LL_RemoveNode()` also leaks memory and does not properly update `count`.

Comment: Gr8 point but the Insert head is only implmented for the test to function and be able to pass in a pointer. But this gave me a hint to a corner case for the implementation which i missed out on what if the input list to split_odd_and_even is a null pointer or has only one element.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a complete review, it's just a few thoughts from glancing over the code...

**Unnecessary casting on malloc**

You don't need to cast the returned value from `malloc`.  Adding unnecessary casts, adds noise to the code as well as creating potential problems with future refactoring.

**Clean up your comments**

Code for review should be presented in as close to its complete state as possible.  With this in mind, commented out print statements that have helped you with your debugging should be removed.  They add nothing but noise to the code and impair readability.

**Naming & Grouping**

Most of your operations that function on the linked list have `LL_` prefixes which groups the methods together.  Two of them don't `Find_tail_manual` and `split_odd_and_even`.  If these methods are part of the same conceptual block of functionality, they should have the same prefix to complete the grouping.  If they aren't, then in the header they should be declared below all of the `LL_` methods, not in the middle of them (with `LL_RemoveNode` below them).

You also want to try to be consistent with your naming for functions.  Pick a style and stick to it.  Are you starting methods with capital letters `Find_tail_manual`, or lower case `split_odd_and_even`, are you using capitalisation to separate words `LL_RemoveNode` or underscores `LL_Remove_Head`.  When you mix and match styles, it makes the code harder to read and predict if you're changing it.

**tmp or tail**

In `split_odd_and_even`, you're creating a `tail` variable, which you then assign to `tmp`.

```
LL_Node_t * tmp = NULL;
LL_Node_t * removed_node;

//! Pretend tail pointer is not available
LL_Node_t * tail = Find_tail_manual(pList);

//! Save off the tail
tmp  = tail;
```

`tail` is never used again and `tmp` is only ever used as an equality check to detect that you've reached the end of the list.  Generally, it's better to name things so that they can be recognised, so `tmp` isn't a great name.  Particularly in this case, where you already have a variable that contains the value and has a better name `tail`.  Lose `tmp` and just do:

```
LL_Node_t * tail = Find_tail_manual(pList);

while(current != tail)
```

Then we have the comment...

```
//! Pretend tail pointer is not available
```

If you're going to add comments, consider using them to explain 'why' you're doing something in preference of 'what' you're doing.  Why are you pretending the pointer isn't there...  Doing it manually involves some processing, so there's presumably a reason for it, don't leave the next person to look at the code the task of decoding *why* you've done it that way, remember they don't have the context that you have when you're recently written the code.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Missing Corner Cases**

   No check for allocation failure.

   Pedantic: no overflow check with `pList->count++;`

   Many memory leaks - `malloc()`, yet no corresponding `free()`.
2. **Pointers for readability for code**

   Respect presentation width.  If posting needed horizontal scroll bars, it is too wide.  Use an auto formatter to adjust.   Do *not* maintain formatting manually.

   Assign at declaration.  Declare when needed. Rather than the 3 lines, how about 1?:

   ```
   //  LL_Node_t * tmp = NULL;
   //  ...
   //  //! Save off the tail
   //  tmp  = tail;

   LL_Node_t * tmp = tail; //! Save off the tail
   ```

   Excessive blank line - not needed.

   ```
   {

       //! Current node is removed
   ```

   Why the 1 space indent?  A sign of manual formatting.  See above point.

   ```
   LL_Node_t * tmp = (LL_Node_t *)malloc(sizeof(LL_Node_t));
   tmp->pNextNode = NULL;
   tmp->node_data = data;
   ```

   Readability includes review.  Is the below correct size type?  We could look to the header file to find out or .....

   ```
   pList->head = (LL_Node_t *) malloc(sizeof(LL_Node_t));
   ```

   ... use the simple to code, review and update

   ```
   pList->head = malloc(sizeof *(pList->head));
   ```

   Instead of a blank line and `//!`, how about just a blank line?
3. **Logical Errors**

   .
4. **Other problems**

   `printf("Node Addr: %p ... pNode`, yet pointer passed is not `void*`.  This is *undefined behavior* (UB), but usually works.  Compliant alternative `printf("Node Addr: %p ... (void *) pNode`.

   `LL_RemoveNode()` does not decrement `count`;

   No value in printing `" \n"` versus simply `"\n"`.  White-space before `'\n'` tends to create issues - best avoided.

   `void main()` may be invalid on various systems-- use a standard `int  main(void)`.

   Identifiers ending with `_t` are reserved by some compilers.  Use `_T` or in this case, just `#include <stdint.h>` instead of `typedef unsigned int uint32_t;`

---

Overall I found `split_odd_and_even()` excessively cumbersome and so offer a simplification:

```
void split_odd_and_even(LL_LinkedList_t * pList, LL_Node_t ** pOddList,
    LL_Node_t ** pEvenList) {
  LL_Node_t OddEven_Head[2] = { {.pNextNode = NULL}, {.pNextNode = NULL}};
  LL_Node_t *OddEven[2] = {&OddEven_Head[0], &OddEven_Head[1]};
  LL_Node_t * current = pList->head;

  unsigned oe = 0;
  while (current) {
    OddEven[oe]->pNextNode = current;
    OddEven[oe] = current;
    oe = !oe;
    current = current->pNextNode;
  }
  OddEven[0]->pNextNode = NULL;
  OddEven[1]->pNextNode = NULL;

  *pEvenList = OddEven_Head[0].pNextNode;
  *pOddList = OddEven_Head[1].pNextNode;
  pList->head = pList->tail = NULL;
  pList->count = 0;
}
```

Comment: Curious why you would say whitespace before '\n' creates issues?

Comment: @Dexobox Re: "White-space before '\n' tends to create issues" as it is unexpected and not readily noticeable -like `"qwerty\t\n"`. Example: Consider a line orientated text file that establishes a definition like  `"abc=def \n"` vs `"ijk=xyz\n"`.  In the first case, it is not readily identifiable that `abc` is assigned a 4 character array versus a 3 character one.  In the realm of competing styles, best to use the one with least surprises.

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard uint32_t or at least test the size of unsigned int.

```
    typedef unsigned int uint32_t;  /* NO    */
    #include <stdint.h>             /* YES   */
    /* somewhere in the code... */
    assert(sizeof(unsigned int)==4) /* MAYBE */
```

Comment: This code is running on a project with non standard compiler and does not have standard libraries like  <stdint.h>

Comment: @Dexobox Ah. In case stdint.h is missing from the compiler I prefer implementing it myself. The using code is none the wiser, it is clear for most other reviewers of the code what is going on, and in case stdint becomes available for other versions or targets your own file gets shadowed due to inclusion order rules.

Comment: no i think you fail to understand that the code around the api split_odd_and_even() is ancillary as the definition of uint32_t is   defined and controlled by the project settings where the api will eventually reside. The library includes is out of scope for the review either way as mentioned in the problem statement and is simply used for quick prototyping.